# How to keep my Timer going when the browser is closed

Tags: javascript, timer, vanilla-forums

I have a basic timer that I want to leave running while the browser is closed.

Sometimes I will reset it but in general I need it to keep running. Something like tickcounter.com.

The timer is live right now at https://disciplinetimer.netlify.app/

It's working pretty well except for the issue mentioned.

I tried setting up localStorage but that didnt work on Netlify.

Here is the JS code:

```js
var days = 0;
var hours = 0;
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;
var highestDays = 0;
var highestHours = 0;
var highestMinutes = 0;
var highestSeconds = 0;
var appendDays = document.getElementById('days');
var appendHours = document.getElementById('hours');
var appendMinutes = document.getElementById('minutes');
var appendSeconds = document.getElementById('seconds');
var buttonStart = document.getElementById('button-start');
var buttonReset = document.getElementById('button-reset');
var interval; // to store timer values

// Check if there is a saved timer state in local storage
if (localStorage.getItem('timerState')) {
  var timerState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('timerState'));
  days = timerState.days;
  hours = timerState.hours;
  minutes = timerState.minutes;
  seconds = timerState.seconds;
  highestDays = timerState.highestDays;
  highestHours = timerState.highestHours;
  highestMinutes = timerState.highestMinutes;
  highestSeconds = timerState.highestSeconds;
  document.getElementById('last-reset-point').innerText = 'Last reset point: ' + timerState.lastResetPoint;
  document.getElementById('highest-time').innerText = 'Highest time reached: ' + timerState.highestTime;
}

function startTimer() {
  seconds++;

  if (seconds > 59) {
    minutes++;
    seconds = 0;
  }
  if (minutes > 59) {
    hours++;
    minutes = 0;
  }
  if (hours > 23) {
    days++;
    hours = 0;
  }

  // Update the display with leading zeros
  appendDays.innerHTML = (days < 10 ? '0' : '') + days;
  appendHours.innerHTML = (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours;
  appendMinutes.innerHTML = (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes;
  appendSeconds.innerHTML = (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;

  // Update highest time if necessary
  if (days > highestDays || (days === highestDays && hours > highestHours) ||
    (days === highestDays && hours === highestHours && minutes > highestMinutes) ||
    (days === highestDays && hours === highestHours && minutes === highestMinutes && seconds > highestSeconds)) {
    highestDays = days;
    highestHours = hours;
    highestMinutes = minutes;
    highestSeconds = seconds;
    var highestTimeStr = highestDays + ':' + (highestHours < 10 ? '0' : '') + highestHours + ':' + (highestMinutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + highestMinutes + ':' + (highestSeconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + highestSeconds;
    document.getElementById('highest-time').innerText = 'Highest time reached: ' + highestTimeStr;

    // Save the timer state to local storage
    var timerState = {
      days: days,
      hours: hours,
      minutes: minutes,
      seconds: seconds,
      highestDays: highestDays,
      highestHours: highestHours,
      highestMinutes: highestMinutes,
      highestSeconds: highestSeconds,
      lastResetPoint: '00:00:00:00', // Reset point set to 00:00:00:00 on start
      highestTime: highestTimeStr,
    };
    localStorage.setItem('timerState', JSON.stringify(timerState));
  }
}

buttonStart.onclick = function() {
  // Clear the interval to avoid multiple timers running
  clearInterval(interval);

  // Start the timer
  interval = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
};

buttonReset.onclick = function() {
  // Clear the interval to stop the timer
  clearInterval(interval);

  // Reset the timer values
  days = 0;
  hours = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  seconds = 0;
  appendDays.innerHTML = '00';
  appendHours.innerHTML = '00';
  appendMinutes.innerHTML = '00';
  appendSeconds.innerHTML = '00';

  // Start the timer immediately after resetting
  interval = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);

  // Save the timer state to local storage with the new reset point
  var resetPointStr = '00:00:00:00';
  var timerState = {
    days: days,
    hours: hours,
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds,
    highestDays: highestDays,
    highestHours: highestHours,
    highestMinutes: highestMinutes,
    highestSeconds: highestSeconds,
    lastResetPoint: resetPointStr,
    highestTime: highestDays + ':' + (highestHours < 10 ? '0' : '') + highestHours + ':' + (highestMinutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + highestMinutes + ':' + (highestSeconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + highestSeconds,
  };
  localStorage.setItem('timerState', JSON.stringify(timerState));

  // Update the last reset point display
  document.getElementById('last-reset-point').innerText = 'Last reset point: ' + resetPointStr;
};
```

```html
<h1>Stopwatch</h1>
<div>
  <span id="days">00</span> Days
  <span id="hours">00</span> Hours
  <span id="minutes">00</span> Minutes
  <span id="seconds">00</span> Seconds
</div>
<button id="button-start">Start</button>
<button id="button-reset">Reset</button>
<p id="last-reset-point"></p>
<p id="highest-time"></p>
```

Comment: Nothing is running on the client when the browser is closed.  A timer can't be running.  What you can do is store the last time seen into localstorage, then load that again when the browser goes back to your site.

Comment: You can't. You would need a server application that is running in the background that updates the server because once the server is closed, none of your websites Javascript is going to run because that is not what JavaScript is about. So you can use something like PHP or NodeJS for the server.

Comment: Look into building a web application, which you can host in IIS. Using MVC or Blazor, you can store users' progress on server side, so you aren't relying on anything on the users browser's side. Then you can have a user store a cookie as their identification, and load in their progress using the identifier you get from their browser.

Comment: Thanks guys, all great solutions. What one would be easiest to work out for a beginner like myself? 

The first one "What you can do is store the last time seen into localstorage, then load that again when the browser goes back to your site" doesn't sound too daunting.

Comment: The cool thing about modern web apps like Blazor, is that you can download a free version of Visual Studio, start a Blazor app, and you start off with a fully working app right away that you can run. All you need to do after that point is make adjustments as necessary.

Comment: Worth a look, cheers

Comment: To do it the browser-centric way, as soon as a user clicks the start button you can save a cookie of the time that they clicked start. When loading the page as the user comes back, you can check for any existing cookies, and start the timer from what time it currently is minus the time in the cookie.

Comment: I would avoid saving something to `localStorage` every single second. Instead you could do it on the `beforeunload` event to save the value once before the document is unloaded/closed.

Comment: ok some more great ideas. Beforeunload or the cookie way could be a good option

Comment: @maraaaaaaaa I got the cookie method working!!! but I never realised it would stop working if the computer is turned off! At least that is what I have read from research.
So I am going to set up Netlify with Netlify functions and github, see if I can do it this way.